# Как безопасно трансформировать дизайн Ubuntu в Elementary OS

Tags: linux, ubuntu, elementary-os

Как безопасно трансформировать дизайн Ubuntu в Elementary OS так, чтобы остались программы, файлы?

(дизайн - значки,курсор, меню приложений сверху, верхняя панель, фоны, нижние меню)
фото:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: **все** файлы? это невозможно: как минимум, будет отличаться содержимое `/etc/sources.list*` (это ирония, но с достаточным количеством горечи и реальности). // в вопросе явно торчат уши ["ошибки xy"](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/709/178576)

Comment: alexander barakinну, хоть программы оставить можно?

Comment: прочитайте, пожалуйста, вопрос и ответ по приведённой мною ссылке. а потом внесите необходимые пояснения в свой вопрос.

Comment: мне ж просто дизайн из elementary os установить...

Comment: уже теплее. опишите, пожалуйста, что именно вам нужно на самом деле - прямо в тексте вопроса.

Comment: ок, сейчас опишу....

Comment: А почему бы вам просто не установить elementary с прежним разделом home? Программы вы таким образом конечно потеряете, но их настройки сохранятся. Напишите простой баш-скрипт для установки всех ваших программ и делов-то.

Comment: Beast Winterwolf, круто! но как это сделать не понимаю, bash скрипт ещо напишу, но вот как оставить папку home....

Comment: Во время установки системы предлагается указать разделы: http://help.ubuntu.ru/manual/установка Просто укажите старый home для новой системы (и не ставьте галочку "форматировать").

Comment: А в чём проблема, если это всего лишь тема оформления и развивается как ещё один гуй для бубна? Это всё равно что говорить "как мне переставить кубунту на лубунту и не потерять файлы?" Да просто воткни ещё 1 метапакет, перезагрузись и при логине выбери другой гуй.

Answer (score 2):

Трансформировать без полной установки систему не получится (наверно, не представляю это возможным). Можно сделать Ubuntu похожим графически тут все написано [ссылка](http://www.noobslab.com/2014/11/mbuntu-macbuntu-1410-transformation.html)

Comment: я тут нашол такое:

Comment: `
 sudo apt-add-repository ppa:elementary-os/testing
 sudo apt-get update
 sudo apt-get upgrade
 sudo apt-add-repository ppa:elementary-os/daily
 sudo apt-get update
 sudo apt-get install elementary-desktop
`